# Create JSON Array from SQL table with multiple records

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server

I have SQL table called Accts with the data shown in the image. I would like to create a JSON file with the customer numbers an array.

Using the code below I was able to get it in the correct format. How do I get each customer in the Customers array to be surrounded by Quotes?

```
select a.[Name], a.[Identifier], JSON_ARRAY("Customer")as Customers
  from 
     (
       select ltrim(rtrim([Name])) as [Name],ltrim(rtrim([Identifier])) as Identifier,  
       string_agg(cast(ltrim(rtrim(custnmbr)) as varchar(max)), ', ') as Customer
       from [dbo].[AcctReps]
   Group by [Identifier], [Name]
    )a
```

FOR json AUTO, Root('Reps')

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: I can't read that tiny image text on my small laptop screen.

Comment: It is in **your** interest to choose the best tags for your question. "sql" is not useful as a tag because every dbms vendor chooses to implement it differently so there are important syntax differences. So, to get **your** solution quickly don't use "sql" as the tag.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I information on the links was quite insightful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the following assume your query is written in T-SQL. (Ideally you would choose a tag that identifies your dbms.)

`FORMATMESSAGE('"%s"', custnmbr)` will add double quotes around each custnmbr. See [FORMATMESSAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/formatmessage-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AcctReps]
(
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50),
    [Identifier] NVARCHAR(50),
    [custnmbr] NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[AcctReps] ([Name], [Identifier], [custnmbr])
VALUES 
('John Doe', 'JD1', 'CUST001'),
('John Doe', 'JD1', 'CUST002'),
('Jane Smith', 'JS1', 'CUST003'),
('Jane Smith', 'JS1', 'CUST004'),
('Jane Smith', 'JS1', 'CUST005'),
('Bob Johnson', 'BJ1', 'CUST006')
```

```
6 rows affected
```

```
select a.[Name], a.[Identifier], JSON_QUERY('[' + a.Customer + ']') as Customers
from 
(
   select ltrim(rtrim([Name])) as [Name], ltrim(rtrim([Identifier])) as Identifier,  
   string_agg(FORMATMESSAGE('"%s"', cast(ltrim(rtrim(custnmbr)) as varchar(max))), ', ') as Customer
   from [dbo].[AcctReps]
   Group by [Identifier], [Name]
) a
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('Reps')
```

| JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B |
| --- |
| {"Reps":[{"Name":"Bob Johnson","Identifier":"BJ1","Customers":["CUST006"]},{"Name":"Jane Smith","Identifier":"JS1","Customers":["CUST003", "CUST004", "CUST005"]},{"Name":"John Doe","Identifier":"JD1","Customers":["CUST001", "CUST002"]}]} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZNFnYd0I)

Note it is preferrable to provide your own sample data - in a reusable format (NOT images).

```
{
  "Reps": [
    {
      "Name": "Bob Johnson",
      "Identifier": "BJ1",
      "Customers": [
        "CUST006"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "Jane Smith",
      "Identifier": "JS1",
      "Customers": [
        "CUST003",
        "CUST004",
        "CUST005"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "John Doe",
      "Identifier": "JD1",
      "Customers": [
        "CUST001",
        "CUST002"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The code worked and the output is exactly what I was looking for. Apologies for not adding the actual data.  I tried, but the formatting was incorrect so I resorted to pasting the image instead. Thanks again.

Comment: To make text appear in fixed width font just indent by 4 spaces. There is an icon in the toolbar for this too. Search the site help for more on formatting. There are also free sites for converting text into fixed width tables. So many ways to avoid images. Please don't use them for data.

Comment: And please, in future, tag your questions with the database type (which I can still assuming is sql server).